# How to Clear Empty Search values?

Tags: customization, plugin-recommendation, search

I have private pages in my website, so i have used this filter to hide some of the pages,

```
function mySearchFilter($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
        $excludeId = get_option('page_for_posts');
        $query->set('post__not_in', array('267','287'));
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','mySearchFilter');
```

it's working perfectly but if i click empty search means it shows some default pages .. how to restrict the empty search?

I tried this one and it's not working for me.

```
  add_filter( 'request', 'my_request_filter' );
    function my_request_filter( $query_vars ) {
        if( isset( $_GET['s'] ) && empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
            $query_vars['s'] = " ";
        }
        return $query_vars;
    }
```

this is my search form

```
      <form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/">
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="search_text" name="s" id="s" value="<?php echo trim( get_search_query() ); ?>" />
    <!--<input type="text" class="search_text" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" />-->
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" class="search_btn" value="" />

  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

i added this

```
$query_vars['s'] = "Please Enter Keyword to search ";
```

It's working.this may question may useful for some other.:)
anyhow thanks friends.